# Как реализовать шифрование слова цифрами?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как реализовать шифрование слова цифрами? Первой букве, а так же всем ее повторениям присваивается 0, следующей 1, и т.д. Регистр не учитывается.
Пример:
hello -> 0.1.2.2.3
hellohello -> 0.1.2.2.3.0.1.2.2.3

У меня получилось сделать без учета повторения

```
function wordPattern(word) {
    let count = 0;
    let arr = word.toString().toUpperCase().split("");
    for (let i=0, i<arr.lenght, i++) {
        arr[i] !== arr[i+1] ? arr[i] = count & count++ : arr[i] = count
    }
    return arr.join (".") ;
}
console.log(wordPattern("hellohello"));
```

Есть мысли, что надо через forEach, но как сделать не пойму

Comment: А "шифрование" не предполагает, что полученную строку потом нужно будет расшифровать?) Как собраетесь отличить `hello` от `kitty` если оба на выходе будут давать `0.1.2.2.3` ?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME если в начале шифруемой строки использовать в качестве ключа перемешанный полный алфавит, то расшифровать "шифровку" можно будет как раз с помощью этого ключа. Ну а как создавать ключ перемешиванием алфавита - тут вариантов для латинского  - 26 факториал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Разбиваем строку на символы, используя`split`.
2. С помощью `Set` создаём массив с уникальными символами.
3. Заменяем каждый символ оригинальной строки индексом массива с уникальными символами.

```js
const str = "hElLoHellO";
const splited = str.toLowerCase().split('');
const unique = [...new Set(splited)];
const res = splited.map(item => unique.indexOf(item)).join('.');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Спасибо, я зациклился на счетчике и даже не подумал что можно сделать через индексы.

Comment: Исправил, чтобы не учитывало регистр.